# Unit test framework using deployment directories when deployment is disabled - how to clear?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Environment: Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Using the MS Unit Test Framework I have many projects in a solution that run fine, either with or without deployment enabled in the testsettings file.  One project, when run with deployment DISABLED insists on looking for files in the deployment directory and consequently fails since the context is without deployment. I cannot find where or how VS has decided for this 1 project (out of many) it should be using a deployment directory (i.e. TestResults/......

Can any one suggest how to get VS to make this project behave just like all others in the solution. Also, no class attributes for deployment items are in use for this set of test classes.